# Help with IF ELSE Statement in AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to add another piece of logic to this working code below to check if there guess is correct for those who fall after the else statement only.

```ampscript
%%[
SET @sid = QueryParameter('sid')
SET @First = QueryParameter('fname')
SET @Last = QueryParameter('lname')
SET @Email = QueryParameter('email')
SET @Guess = QueryParameter('Guess')
SET @Lookup = LOOKUPROWS("FnameLname", "EmailAddress", @Email)
IF ROWCOUNT(@Lookup) > 0 THEN
]%%
 <p style="color:red">Sorry! You have already entered the trivia competition.</p>
%%[else]%%

%%[InsertData("FnameLname","FirstName", @First,"LastName", @Last,"SubscriberKey", @sid,"Guess", @Guess,"EmailAddress", @Email)]%%

%%[ENDIF]%%
```

I have tried this but cant get it to work. Not sure where the syntax is wrong.

```ampscript
%%[
SET @sid = QueryParameter('sid')
SET @First = QueryParameter('fname')
SET @Last = QueryParameter('lname')
SET @Email = QueryParameter('email')
SET @Guess = QueryParameter('Guess')
SET @Lookup = LOOKUPROWS("FnameLname", "EmailAddress", @Email)
IF ROWCOUNT(@Lookup) > 0 THEN
]%%
 <p style="color:red">Sorry! You have already entered the trivia competition.</p>
%%[ELSE]%%

%%[InsertData("FnameLname","FirstName", @First,"LastName", @Last,"SubscriberKey", @sid,"Guess", @Guess,"EmailAddress", @Email)]%%

%%[ IF @Guess != "OscarRobertson" THEN ]%%

You are wrong!<br>

%%[ELSE]%%

Your are correct!

%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

Thanks for any help in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you're missing the second `endif`, give this a try:

```ampscript
%%[
SET @sid = QueryParameter('sid')
SET @First = QueryParameter('fname')
SET @Last = QueryParameter('lname')
SET @Email = QueryParameter('email')
SET @Guess = QueryParameter('Guess')
SET @Lookup = LOOKUPROWS("FnameLname", "EmailAddress", @Email)
IF ROWCOUNT(@Lookup) > 0 THEN
]%%
 <p style="color:red">Sorry! You have already entered the trivia competition.</p>
%%[ELSE]%%

%%[InsertData("FnameLname","FirstName", @First,"LastName", @Last,"SubscriberKey", @sid,"Guess", @Guess,"EmailAddress", @Email)]%%

%%[ IF @Guess != "OscarRobertson" THEN ]%%

You are wrong!<br>

%%[ELSE]%%

Your are correct!

%%[ ENDIF ]%%
%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

Every conditional statement needs it's own closing, or to say differently, every `if` needs an `endif`.

Websites like https://ampscript.io/ can help you with checking the synatx of your script :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked perfectly. I will definitely use https://ampscript.io/ .